# as3 | trying to add multiple "onClick" events - how do I do that?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, onclick, flash-cs5, addeventlistener

I am trying to create multiple addEventListener but I don't know how. As you can see in the code below - I don't understand what I need to write where I wrote ???????? in order to produce multiple functions (such as onClick1,onClick2,onClick3, etc...)

```
for (i=0; i < numberOfResults; i++)
{
    videoResults[i] = new Object();
    videoResults[i].movie = new MovieClip();
    stage.addChild(videoResults[i].movie);
    videoResults[i].movie.addEventListener("click",?????????);
    function ?????????(event)
    {

    }

}
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: In this case I think you should explain what your end goal is (ie. why are you wanting to create all these listener functions) so that we can explain a better way of achieving that goal. Creating functions inside a loop is a bad idea, so we need a higher level understanding of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to write a function inside of a for loop. Do something like this:

```
for (i=0; i < numberOfResults; i++)
{
    videoResults[i] = new Object();
    videoResults[i].movie = new MovieClip();
    stage.addChild(videoResults[i].movie);
    videoResults[i].movie.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, myMadeUpCallbackEvent);    
}


function myMadeUpCallbackEvent(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
   //In order to be able to tell which clip has called this callback, you can compare the properties of evt.currentTarget. The evt is the Event object cast into a reference. evt.currentTarget is the target or object that called the event. So you can do something like this:
   trace(MovieClip(evt.currentTarget).name); to get the unique name of the caller
}
```

You may be interested in this free video tutorial website on flash:

http://gotoandlearn.com/

Comment: thanks a lot! but I still don't understand how to connect the dots.. let's say that if I click the Nth movie clip - I want to add this line: videoResults[N].isItclicked = true; what do I need to do and what am I missing here?

Comment: That question could call for a complicated answer and a lot of discussion here that would lead away from the original question topic. What I think would be best is for me to provide a link to a tutorial on how to create a video player with a playlist in flash AS3. Any new questions can be posted as independent questions here just to keep the questions and answers clear. http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3xmlvideoplayer/

Comment: Use a Dictionary instead of an Array to store the click results. A Dictionary can use any object (for example, a MovieClip) as the key, rather than just numbers.